# carrierwave AJAX upload with remotipart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, file-upload, carrierwave, remotipart

In my rails4 I would like to submit a form via AJAX that has a file uploaded via **carrierwave**. As far as I know it can be done via **remotipart**, but can't figure it out how I can do that. (Remotipart installed properly since it's working with refile gem that I also use in the app.)

With the current code below the form gets submitted according to the logs and it says the `create.js.erb` is rendered, but the code in the `create.js.erb` file never runs.

```
Rendered posts/create.js.erb (387.0ms)
```

What should I do?

form

```
<%= form_for @post, remote: true, method: :post, :html => { :multipart => true, class: "post-create-form" } do |f| %>
  <img id="img_prev" style="margin-bottom:10px;" width=300 height=200 src="#" class="img-thumbnail hidden"/>
  <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Share something useful..", class: "form-control post-create-body" %>
  <%= f.button "SHARE", class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-create-post", data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Saving..."} %>
  <span class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-message-file">Upload Image
    <%= f.file_field :post_image, class: "choose-message-file", id: "avatar-upload" %>
  </span>
  <%= f.hidden_field :post_image_cache %>
<% end %>
```

create.js.erb

```
$('ul.errors').hide();
$('.alert-danger').hide();
$('.post-index').prepend('<%= j render @post %>');
$('.post-create-body').val('');
$('.btn-create-post').prop('disabled',true);
```

_post.html.erb

```
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <%= link_to user_path(post.user) do %>
        <%= image_tag post.user.avatar.url(:base_thumb), class: 'post-avatar' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="post-info">
        <%= link_to user_path(post.user) do %>
          <span class="post-user-name"><%= post.user.full_name %></span>
        <% end %>
        <span class="post-updated"><%= local_time_ago(post.updated_at) %></span>
      </div>
      <div class="post-body">
        <%= simple_format(find_links(h post.body)) %>
      </div>
      <div class="post-image" data-postlink="<%= post_path(post) %>">
        <% if post.post_image? %>
          <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#post-image-modal">
            <%= image_tag post.post_image.url(:base_thumb) %>
          </button>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

UPDATE:
The problem is connected to updating the post object. The update form code can be found in the `_post.html.erb`, so that's why `<%= j render @post %>` didn't work. Still don't know what the problem is.

So what works:
1. creating post that has no image
2. updating post that has no image
3. updating post that has image BUT image is not edited
Not working:
1. creating post that has image
2. updating post that has image which is edited

```
<%= form_for post, method: :patch, remote: true, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <div class="modal fade updatepost" id="updatepost_<%= post.id %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content" style="text-align:left">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="edittaskmodalohhhhh">Edit Task</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none">
            <ul class="errors" style="display:none">
              <%= render 'layouts/error_messages', object: f.object %>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="field form-group">
             <%= f.file_field :post_image, id: "avatar-upload-update" %>
             <%= f.hidden_field :post_image_cache %>
          </div>
          <div class="field form-group">
            <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control edit-post-body" %>
          </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="updatepostclose">Close</button>
            <%= f.button "Update post", class: 'btn btn-primary edit-post-submit', data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Saving..."} %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

update.js.erb

```
$("ul.errors").html("");
<% if @post.errors.any? %>
   $('.alert-danger').show();
   $('ul.errors').show();
   <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
     $("ul.errors").append($("<li />").html("<%= message.html_safe %>"));
   <% end %>
<% else %>
  $('ul.errors').hide();
  $('.alert-danger').hide();
  $('#updatepost_<%= @post.id %>').modal('hide');
  $post = $('<%= j render @post %>');
  editPostHideDanger($post);
  $('#post_<%= @post.id %>').remove();
  $(".new-post-insert").prepend($post);
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
<% end %>
```

Comment: Your form does not have `:html => { :multipart => true }` . Try adding this.
`<%= form_for @post, remote: true, method: :post, class: "post-create-form", :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>`

Comment: dkp, it didn't help :(

Comment: can you post stack trace after submitting the form ?

Comment: I updated the question. I also checked if remotipart is used with `if remotipart_submitted?`. It's true as you see in the logs. It printed REMOTION. Form is working via js properly if there is only text.

Comment: dkp, any other idea?

Comment: `Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (78.1ms)` - This means the `post` partial is also getting rendered correctly which has been placed within `create.js.erb`. Everything seems to be correct. Just make sure your  classes are available in DOM.

Comment: I don't know what can be different, since if I share the post with no image then it's working fine.

Comment: `Unpermitted parameter: post_image_cache` - why do you have `post_image_cache` in the form when you are not permitting in controller.

Comment: Yeah I realized 15mins ago, but with having that permitted it's still the same. I also checked with no image preview and image_cache, but it was the same.

Comment: So the problem is this line `$('.post-index').prepend('<%= j render @post %>');` in `create.js.erb`. The weird thing is that if I create the post without pic then it works fine. Any idea?

Comment: Is there something in `post` partial that is dealing with the uploaded image ? & that is silently getting skipped if you do not have an image ?

Comment: I updated my question again. This part belongs to the displayed pic. I can't imagine what the problem can be, since if I reload the page/ share the js with no pic everything works fine.

Comment: `<% if post.post_image.present? %>
          <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#post-image-modal">
            <%= image_tag post.post_image.url(:base_thumb) %>
          </button>
        <% end %>`   - Can you modify this section of your partial

Comment: Not good. I tried to take out the whole code snippet as well, but it's still the same.

Comment: dkp, getting closer. Can you guess what can go wrong with the update form?

Comment: I am not sure why `remotipart` with `remote: true` and `multipart: true` is not working for you. I have used `remotipart`, it works like a charm. I just have to install the gem and add `//= require jquery.remotipart` to my `application.js` . Your update form also looks fine to me.

Comment: This is something connected to the bootstrap modal. I always have trouble with it. The create form and the update forms (as many as objects) are on the same page. That's the basic issue and it can causes a lot of problem.

Comment: dkp, I could solve it with changing the structure of the modals. But still don't know the reason. Bootstrap modals can behave like a bitch sometimes. And it was also hard to track down, since without the image the form worked perfectly......

Answer (score 0):

There was some issue (still don't know what) with the bootstrap modals. I changed the structure of the modals and now it's working fine.